# SOQL returns records outside the specified date range

Tags: soql, rest-api, datetime

Any explanation why the following query with *greater than* operator

`SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE CreatedDate > 2017-04-10T12:30:47+00:00`

returns also items with `CreatedDate=2017-04-10T12:30:47+00:00` ?

I suspect dates are internally stored with higher precision, but returned with seconds rounded to integer values.

Originally I though it could be somehow related to time zone shift (client vs. server), but when the time zone is specified directly, I suppose no further modification takes place.

Comment: Salesforce does not store millisecond precision as far as I can tell. It may very well be a difference in time zone based on the user's Salesforce settings. I have tried several variants of your query using records in my org, and I am consistently seeing that records that exactly meet the CreatedDate value are not included in the result set when using the greater-than operator. What client are you using?

Comment: Same as with sfdcfox, I can't reproduce your scenario with a record in one of my own orgs through either the dev console or through workbench.developerforce.com (using the REST explorer).